# Add integer to a float and get the output as float in r

Tags: r, floating-point, numeric, digits, output-formatting

```
x <- 1626307200

y = 0.034

x+y
```

I want to add these two numbers in r and save it as a float (1626307200.034).
Both numbers are in numeric format.
Tried several ways but didn't work

Comment: The result is still of type `double`. R prints numbers with a maximum of `getOption("digits")` significant digits. You can increase this maximum with, e.g., `options(digits = 16)`. Now R prints `x + y` as `1626307200.034`.

Comment: You can check the value with `sprintf("%.3f",x+y)`.

Comment: just store `z <- x+y` z is the correct value. Probably you are wondering you cannot see it. Just know `z!=x`. Also you can get the decimal part of z ie `z%%1`

Comment: You can also use a `digits` argument directly in `print()` without changing your global options, e.g., `print(x + y, digits = 15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command to allow R to display more digits:

```
options(digits = 15)
x <- 1626307200
y <- 0.034

z = x + y
z # 1626307200.034
```